# tar Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Tags: backup, tar

I am trying to backup my Ubuntu workstation by the help of [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) and are running into trouble as the tar command outputs

> `Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`.

Here's what I ran in terminal:

```
sudo -i
cd /
tar -cvpzf sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz \
    --exclude=/sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz \
    --exclude=/proc \
    --exclude=/lost+found \
    --exclude=/sys \
    --exclude=/mnt \
    --exclude=/media \
    --exclude=/dev /
```

So from searching a bit, the error seems to be of a non-critical nature, but as I checkout the contents of the actual .tar file, my `/home`-folder is missing, so obviously something went clearly wrong.

What should I do instead to backup my system without errors?

Comment: `tar` should show what the error is: remove v-verbose flag or send all output to `/dev/null`. You should see more clearly the error messages. Alternatively, send stderr to a file, then show us what is in.

Comment: Also, is the home encrypted? Is accessible from root user?

Comment: /home is not encrypted. It did appear in the rar-file though when I re-ran the command, altough the "exting with failure..." keeps appearing

Comment: It could depend on the absolute path, that distrubs `tar`, try substituting `.` to `/`

Comment: Hi Entzotib. Sorry for the confusion - replace `/` with `/`?

Comment: I said, replace the last `/` on the command line with a dot, `.` or also with `./`

Comment: Oh! Will try it out. Hold on!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest a command line as the following:

```
tar -cvpzf sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz --one-file-system \
    --exclude=/sysbackup-20110821.tar.gz \
    --exclude=./run \
    --exclude=./tmp \
    --exclude='./home/*/.gvfs' ./
```

As you see, every exclude pattern becomes a relative path, and the `--one-file-system` option excludes `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, and everything mounted under `/media` or `/mnt`.

Nevertheless, if you have a separate home partition, this is not backed up.

Tested on 11.10 (Oneiric, alpha3). Probably, in previous ubuntu versions you should exclude `./var/run`, instead of `/run`.

Answer (score 1):

Right click，choose "**Extract here**". I use this way to resolve another familiar problem. But I don't know why it can work. It looks incredibly simple, isn't it? Hopefully that can help you.