# "Cannot open: Permission denied" when creating a tar file

Tags: permissions, tar

I need to to create a archive from my ftp server (all of the /usr/src/ directory) using tar command. However I keep getting permission denied error. Here is step by step what I am doing:

```
canserhan@embserv:~$ cd /usr/src/

canserhan@embserv:/usr/src$ ls
kernel-headers-2.6.8-2       linux                rtlinux-3.2-pre3
kernel-headers-2.6.8-2-386   linux-2.4.21         rtlinux3.2-move
kernel-kbuild-2.6-3          linux-2.6.9-rtlfree
kernel-source-2.6.8.tar.bz2  rtlinux

canserhan@embserv:/usr/src$ tar cvf rtl_archive.tar /usr/src/
tar: rtl_archive.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

canserhan@embserv:/usr/src$
```

What I am doing wrong? Seems like the problem is with my output archive file. But I could not exactly figure out what should I do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that you are executing the command inside `/usr/src` to which you do not have write permissions with your credentials. Therefore you do not have write permissions for the `.tar` file you are trying to create. Use `tar cvf /tmp/rtl_archive.tar /usr/src` to create a tar-file where writing is possible.

Generally you can give any path that you have write access to, such as:

```
tar cvf $HOME/rtl_archive.tar /usr/src
```

to create the `.tar` file in.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It seems like it worked, it created a rtl_archive under /tmp/ however I got an error during the operation: "tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors " How can I fix this?

Comment: See this similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58144/tar-exiting-with-failure-status-due-to-previous-errors Probably there is something in the directories that cannot be included in a tar-file (such as a pipe). This is not a critical error, so tar continues. Do not use the v parameter (`tar cf /tmp/rtl_archive.tar /usr/src`) to reduce the output - you should then see the "real" error.

Comment: Vielen, herzlichen Dank!

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the same issue and this method works great! (I didn't want to start messing with the existing permissions on the directory itself.)